# Send commands from Windows Service to a running WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I have two separate programs.  One is a winform that hosts a running process with output/input being redirected through the form.  The process is a canned product with little chance of being able to modify it myself.

The second program is a service that can pole data from the running process but it doesn't interact with the winform directly.

My goal is to send a string from the service to the winform to then interact with the running process.  OR, I wouldn't mind being able to send commands directly to the process but I'm betting that can't happen without modifying the running process source.

I've look at Named Pipes but I'm not sure that that is the best means.  Both programs are hosted on the same machine.  I'm just not sure what my options are.  Any ideas?  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full range if IPC (Inter-Process Communication) options available in Windows is outlined [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

- Clipboard
- COM
- Data Copy
- DDE
- File Mapping
- Mailslots
- Pipes
- RPC
- Windows Sockets

Then there are mechanisms outside of Windows

- [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or similar [queue systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)
- Record commands/state in a database or file

Of all these, Named Pipes is probably the best fit for your particular application.  I have used them for similar things in the past.  They are easy to setup and use.

Comment: Suppose I'll keep looking into Named Pipes then.  From the MSDN examples I see, it looks like my service must absolutely spawn the winform process.  Is that correct?

That would make my process slightly weird lol

Comment: @Residualfail: No, the processes can be started independently of each other.  Neither must be a child of the other.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to achieve this communication. Mainly you can use [Named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) (WCF), [MSMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C)